# Use of undeclared identifier 'importMenu'

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting the above error in objective c when i'm compiling.I don't know why I'm getting this.

below are the coded file

**Test.m** file

```
- (void)displayDocumentPicker:(NSArray *)UTIs withSenderRect:(CGRect)senderFrame
{
    UIViewController * vc = nil;
    [importMenu addOptionWithTitle:@"Photos & Videos" image:nil order:UIDocumentMenuOrderFirst handler:^{

        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePickerController.sourceType];
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        [self.viewController presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];
    if (!IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"11.0")) {
        vc = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:UTIs inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
        ((UIDocumentMenuViewController *)vc).delegate = self;
        vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.viewController.view;
        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(senderFrame, CGRectZero)) {
            vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = senderFrame;
        }
    } else {
        vc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:UTIs inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
        ((UIDocumentPickerViewController *)vc).delegate = self;
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    }

    [self.viewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**Test.h** file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface FilePicker : CDVPlugin <UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CDVPluginResult * pluginResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CDVInvokedUrlCommand * command;

- (void)isAvailable:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void)pickFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Do I need to add any headers in Test.h file?

Comment: Where is importMenu declared?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you never defined importMenu.

How about adding something like `UIDocumentMenuViewController * importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController();`, or maybe the non-deprecated class `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?